# Table query / filter using a hash in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, hash, sqlite

I'm using ruby on rails 4 and SQLite3.  I'd like to query a table/model using a hash of Column => Value combinations.  Given the hash:

```
 a = {"Size" => 1, "Type" => "Tall", "Material" => "Metal", "Option 1" => "Yes", "Option 2" => "No"}
```

and the table PARTS:

```
PART     SIZE     TYPE     MATERIAL    OPTION 1     OPTION 2
A1234    1        Tall     
A1233    2        Tall
A1232    3        Tall
A1231    4        Tall
A8787                      Plastic
A8786-01                   Metal       Yes
A8786-02                   Metal       No
A8785                      Liquid
A6543                                                Yes
```

I would like the query to look at each column, and return all `Parts` that contain the value given in the hash, as well as any instances that contain nil or blank.  So the value `"Option 1" => "Yes"` should keep A8786-01 as well as all other parts in that column that are blank.  Or in other words, A8786-02 will be eliminated.

The hash shown above would return Parts `["A1234", "A8786-01"]`.  Can this be done with a single method?  Or a string of scopes?  I'm open to any good way of going about this.  I thought this might include looping through the Hash using a.each, but I'm unsure how it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic `where` method:

```
attrs = {"Size" => 1, "Type" => "Tall", "Material" => "Metal", "Option 1" => "Yes", "Option 2" => "No"}
Part.where(attrs)
```

Returns `Part` records **matching exactly each of the given values** for each attributes.

---

Another way to do it:

```
attrs = {"Size" => 1, "Type" => "Tall", "Material" => "Metal", "Option 1" => "Yes", "Option 2" => "No"}
sql_query = attrs.map { |col, val| "(parts.#{sanitize(col)} = #{sanitize(val)} OR pars.#{sanitize(col)} IS NULL)" }.join(" AND ")
Part.where(sql_query)
```

Returns `Part` records **matching each of the given values OR having `NULL` values** (but not empty strings `""`) **for the given columns**.

I already see a flaw here: it will return `Part` records having `NULL` values for each "wanted values". Example:

```
# consider this dummy data
# PART     SIZE     TYPE     MATERIAL    OPTION 1     OPTION 2
# A1234    1        Tall     
# A1233

attrs = { "Size" => 1, "Type" => "Tall" }
sql_query = attrs.map { |col, val| "(parts.#{sanitize(col)} = #{sanitize(val)} OR pars.#{sanitize(col)} IS NULL)" }.join(" AND ")
Part.where(sql_query)
# will returns A1234 AND A1233 records
```

Comment: Actually I think the "flaw" is exactly what I want it to do.  If you think about an excel spreadsheet with filters, I basically want to go through each column, and select one attribute value, as well as all blanks, nulls, and empty strings, so I would want that search to return both A1234 and A1233 unless there is a value in SIZE or TYPE other than 1 and Tall.  I'll give this a try and see if it works!

Comment: Is there anything else I could put in my answer to solve your issue @sabrams ?

Comment: I don't think so.  I'll plug it into my code this afternoon and select your answer if there's no major issues.  Thank you!

Comment: The #{sanitize(col)} is throwing a nomethoderror on sanitize.

Comment: This method `sanitize` is an ActiveRecord method. You can use it directly in an ActiveRecord context (like in a model) but won't be directly available elsewhere (like in controllers or views). Use the "full path" to the method to call it from a controller/view : `ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(...)`